# display none ie9 crash with float left elements

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

When i click the hyperlink "off" then "on" in the following html sample, (very boiled down code), ie9 crashes

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <DIV style="display: inline;">
        <A style="float: left;">always&nbsp;</A>
    </DIV>

    <DIV style="display: inline;" id="hideMe">
        <A style="float: left;">some</A>
        <A style="float: left;">times&nbsp;</A>
    </DIV>

    <DIV style="display: inline;">
        <A style="float: left;">always&nbsp;</A>
    </DIV>

    <DIV>
        <A onclick="{document.getElementById('hideMe').style.display = 'inline';}" href="#">on</A>
        <A onclick="{document.getElementById('hideMe').style.display = 'none';}" href="#">off</A>
    </DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I am unsure what to do next, i can't see an fundamental problem with the code, it evens passes HTML 4.01 Strict! validation.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Crashes? You mean the browser shuts down?

Comment: Yes, as in you get a popup "Internet Explorer has stopped working"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have IE9 to hand to test this, but just looking at the code I would say that the fundamental problem is `float`s inside `inline` elements.

`inline` elements are not supposed to contain any block content (including floats).

If you need this kind of layout, you should use `display:inline-block` instead of `inline`, although I think the floats will still be unnecessary, as the links should line up to the left within their contain anyway.

I think that should solve the problem.

Having said all that, if you've crashed the browser then it is a browser bug, regardless of the quality or validity of the code. The browser should be able to deal gracefully with this kind of thing; a crash is bad news. You should report it to Microsoft, even if you do manage to work around it. (it will be particularly helpful for them that you've got a simple test case to demonstrate the problem)

Comment: I tested the code in Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7 and confirmed that it does, in fact, crash. Removing the floats fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input Spudley, I will investigate this further, aceept your answer soon.